# где найти? discord.py

Tags: python, discord.py

хотел бы узнать, как называется вот эта штука? Но никак не могу дать ей название чтобы загуглить, может кто подскажет как она называется и в какой части документации она находится?[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: это называется выпадающее меню.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=56XoybDajjA